# How to get related objects

Tags: django

I have 2 models :
-products
-review

Every product has one or more reviews.

Question : How I can get this related object's in view and pass him into template.

```py
def product_detail(request, id, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id, slug=slug, available=True)
    cart_product_form = CartAddProductForm()
    reviews = Review.objects.filter()
    template = 'shop/product/detail.html'
    return render_to_response(template,
                              {'product': product,
                               'cart_product_form': cart_product_form,
                               'reviews': reviews})
```

```py
class Review(models.Model):
    RATING_CHOICES = (
        (1, '1'),
        (2, '2'),
        (3, '3'),
        (4, '4'),
        (5, '5'),
    )
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    rating = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES, default=5)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.user
```

Comment: Why do you need to do it in the view, particularly? Either way, it would be `product.review_set.all()`, although in the template you don't need the parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How i can get this related object's in view and pass him into template.

You don't need to pass these in the template. In the template you can render these as:

```
{% for review in product.review_set.all %}
    {{ review.text }}
{% endfor %}
```

In case you want to render the related set of *multiple* items, it is better to use a [**`.prefetch_related(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) call to prefetch all the related objects in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter, passing on the Review objects, the product you are trying to get:

```
  Review.objects.filter(product__id=productid)
```

This will retrieve all the reviews of that product, you can get this in some method of the view and pass to a template with a context

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/